# using colorbox over another colorbox using jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, colorbox

i have a page where i'm using a  with id="emailfrnd", from the following script i successfully implemented the colorbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#emailfrnd").colorbox({
        inline: true,
        href:"#ef",
        close:"",
    opacity:0.95,
        onClosed:function(){
            //window.parent.location.reload(true);
        }
         });
 });
</script>
```

now the new colorbox contains a form with a send button in it of id "emailfrnd_submit" now i had written some validations using the jquery & ajax and if there are no errorMessages i'll get another colorbox and the code is as follows:

```
if (errorMessage == '') {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: root_url + '/services/services.php?method=emailfrnd',
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $("#emailfrnd_submit").colorbox({
                    inline: false,
                    close: "",
                    html: "<div style='height:230px;width:400px;display:block;'><p style='color:black;font:16px verdana;'>Your email was successfully sent.</p><br/><p style='color:gray; font:16px verdana;'>Thank you for telling your friend</p><div id='emailfrnd_sub' style='width: 50px;margin-top:30px;float: right;'><input type='submit' value='OK' name='emailfrnd_submit' id='emailfrnd_sub' class='redbut' style='float:right;position:absolute;right: 198px;margin-top: 0px;color:white;'></div></div>",
                    opacity: 0.95,
                    onClosed: function () {
                        //window.parent.location.reload(true);
                    }
                });
                //window.location.assign("../index.php");
            } else {
                alert('mail not send');
            }
        }
    });
} else {
    alert(errorMessage);
}
});
```

upto now i succeed in getting the things as i want, here after doing the validations and onclick the send button according to this code a new colorbox with the html content as above is coming, here i have a Ok button here, i want to make that button as the closing button of this colorbox. how can i get that functionality for the ok button here??
anyone help is much appreciated....thanks in advance.....

Comment: no one is there to solve this for me??

Comment: Why have 2 colorboxes?  Just utilize the one, with a div "status" field saying that submit was completed or failed.  Then have the submit button be replaced with an Exit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need 2 colorboxes to do it**.
Why don't you simple create a `div` which class is `message_content` and you update it's text according to the ajax status ?
It's much better.

**Example**:

**html**:

```
<div id="colorbox_content"> //@todo: change to colorbox id

    <form id="your_form">   //@todo: change according to your form id

    </form>

    <div class="message_content">

        <p class="message"></p>
        <span class="close"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Close</a></span>

    </div>

</div>
```

**js**:

```
/**
 * Close message
 */
jQuery('#colorbox_content').on('click', '.close', function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('#message_content').slideUp();
});

/**
 * On form submit
 */
if (errorMessage == '') {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: root_url + '/services/services.php?method=emailfrnd',
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                var message = "Your email was successfully sent.";
                //window.location.assign("../index.php");
            } else {
                var message = "Your email was successfully sent.";
            }
            jQuery('#colorbox_content').slideDown().find('.message').text(message);
        }
    });
} else {
    alert(errorMessage);
}
```

Update based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566580/using-colorbox-over-another-colorbox-using-jquery-ajax/11571246#comment15310468_11571246) comment:

If you want the same funcionality for different buttons you have to use the same `class` for them.
here's what do you need.
[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4vuDC/187/)

I changed some `ids` to `classes` so you don't need 2 events with the same code.

And here's the [**las version**](http://jsfiddle.net/4vuDC/190/).
You can see that you can store your `options` for each kind of colorbox and then pass them thrue parameter.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer and the fiddile shows how to do it.....::::)))))
http://jsfiddle.net/srinivaswaterdrop01/4vuDC/189/

Comment: So, you got how to do it, great. But it's not the best way, if you look my updated answer you'll see that it can be better.